# How to draw a circle in front of a textview with canvas in android

Tags: android, canvas, view, textview, draw

I made a code where a circle moves around, but whenever it moves in front of a textview, the textview gets in front of him and I want him to be in front of the textview.
I tried drawing the circle after making the textview but it doesn't fix it.
Example:

```
public MainView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    ((ViewGroup) text.getParent()).removeView(text);//the text was already added to the activity
    Paint paint=new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawCircle(0.0,0.0,500.0, paint);
    main.addContentView(text, parameters);//adding a textview named text in the activity
    invalidate();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create Views inside onDraw, it's called so many times and you will have a lot of TextViews but you only need one, normally created on activity onCreate.

The TextView seems in front due the children is clipped when drawing, try setting clipChildren to false in the ViewGroup container